# Changing background colour of a paper-dropdown-menu

Tags: dart, paper-elements

I have a paper-droopdown-menu that displays normally. But I would like to change the backgroud colour as shown in the graphic below [image]

I have tried the following but it did not affect the background.

```
 * /deep/ paper-dropdown-menu::shadow #menu {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: You want to change the background of the input field part?

Comment: Yes. The entire white rectangle that includes the white part above and below the black line in the indicated area. I know how to change the colour of the menu containing the paper-items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
  paper-dropdown-menu {
    background-color: red;
  }
```

or just the input element

```css
  paper-dropdown-menu::shadow #control {
    background-color: red;
  }
```

If this isn't what you want, can you please add the HTML to your question that produces the layout you have in your screenshot.